# How do I debug why a key mapping is randomly getting removed in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

I use the `<C-k>` keybind in insert mode to display function signature information, i.e.:

```
lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()
```

This works, but this key map is regularly getting mysteriously removed. All of a sudden, rather than getting signature information, I just insert a bunch of `^K^K^K`s instead. (This is what happens when `<C-k>` isn't bound to anything.)

If I just restart the LSP server, so my `on_attach` function is run again, the keybind is restored.

But why the heck does it randomly get unbound? This is the only key map this happens with, all the other ones are unaffected.

I'm guessing there is a misbehaving plugin causing this, but without a reliable way to replicate the issue it's going to be a massive undertaking to use the process of elimination.

Are there any built-in mechanisms for troubleshooting this faster? Can I log every key mapping (and unmapping) somewhere, for example?

Comment: What does `:verbose imap <C-k>` say before and after the mapping stops working?

Comment: Before, it says `i  <C-K>       *@<Cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>` and "Last set from Lua". Afterwards it just says "no mapping found".

Comment: There is no way to log unmap commands but you can always grep the plugin source code for `unmap` commands.